# Brunch copy files from folder to folder is not working

Tags: brunch

I want to copy my app/adminTool/assets into my public/adminTools folder. Tried using assetsmanager-brunch npm module, but not working, PFB the config.coffee snippet.

```
conventions:
    assets:  /^app(\/|\\)assets(\/|\\)/
    ignored: /^(bower_components\/bootstrap-less(-themes)?|app\/styles\/overrides|(.*?\/)?[_]\w*)/
  assetsmanager:
    copyTo:
      'adminTool': ['app/adminTool/assets/*']
  modules:
    definition: false
    wrapper: false
  paths:
    public: 'public'
```